# How to remove seconds and milliseconds from ISO Date on Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, iso

I have datetime "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z" and I want to remove seconds and milliseconds.
The desired result would be something like this "2021-05-26T06:19:00.000Z" or "2021-05-26T06:19Z"

I manage to remove the milliseconds using replace() method but can't remove seconds

```
let ts = "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";
  console.log(ts);
  ts = ts.replace(/\.\d+/, "");
  console.log(ts)
```

Thanks for taking the time to respond

Comment: `/\.\d+/` -> `/:\d\d\.\d+/`?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the date is always as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you could extract the needed part with this:

```js
const date = "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";

const regex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}/;

const [match] = regex.exec(date);

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the string using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
const str = "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";

const result = `${str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf(":"))}Z`;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to treat the date as a `string`...

```js
const ts = "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";
const result = ts.substring(0, 17) + '00.000Z'; // '2021-05-26T06:19:00.000Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit hacky, but since the ISO Date is properly standardized you could just create a substring and append the timezone information:

```js
function stripSeconds(isoDate) {
    return isoDate.substring(0, 16) + isoDate.substr(23);
}
```

Example:

```js
let full = "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";
let modified = full.substring(0, 16) + full.substr(23)
console.log(modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope it helps,

```
let ts = "2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";
console.log(ts);
  let d = new Date(ts);
  d.setSeconds(0,0);
  console.log(d.toISOString());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want string manupulations:

```js
const timeStr="2021-05-26T06:19:45.854Z";
const dateFromStr = new Date(timeStr)
const dateHours = dateFromStr.getHours()
dateFromStr.setHours(dateHours)
dateFromStr.setSeconds(0)
dateFromStr.setMilliseconds(0)
const dateISO = dateFromStr.toISOString()

const div = document.body.querySelector('#test')
div.textContent= dateISO
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: This sets the local seconds, it should use UTC methods to set the UTC seconds.

Comment: @RobG Does it make big difference if he does not care about seconds? He wants seconds always to be 0.